# Getting all files from various folders and copying them with unique names

Tags: linux, bash

Currently using this command to get all my "fanart" from my TV folder, and dump it into a single folder.

```
find /volume1/tv/ -type f \( -name '*fanart.jpg'* -o -path '*/fanart/*.jpg' -o -path '*/extrafanart/*.jpg' \) -exec cp {} /volume1/tv/_FANART \;
```

Here's the issue: a lot of these files have the same name, and can't be dumped into the same folder. Example:

- Folder A

  - fanart.jpg
- Folder B

  - fanart.jpg

Is there a way to copy these files from their respective folders and give them a unique name in the destination folder? Name needn't be anything descriptive, random is just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want them to be unique? What should happen in case of name collisions?

Comment: And why doe you use `\(` brackets?

Comment: No reason for the \( brackets - I worked off another command that happened to have those.

In the event of a name collision, I'd like it to tack on a suffix, generate a random character string, anything. Doesn't really matter what the files' names are, as long as I can consolidate them all into a single folder. Which I can't right now because of those naming collisions.

Comment: Append MD5 hash to every file. Does that solve your problem ?

Comment: Adding an MD5 would be perfect. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

```
find /volume1/tv/ -type f \( -name '*fanart.jpg'* -o -path '*/fanart/*.jpg' -o -path '*/extrafanart/*.jpg' \) -exec cp --backup=numbered  {} /volume1/tv/_FANART \;
```

..

```
cp --backup=numbered  {}
```

If the file exists, this will not overwrite but make a backup with a number assigned.

The files will be hidden. `Ctrl+H` to view hidden files

Comment: However, that appends to the end of the filename - programs which use the suffix as a clue to their contents will have extra data to filter out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the md5sum as the new name:

```
find /volume1/tv/ -type d -path '/volume1/tv/_FANART' -prune -o -type f \( -name '*fanart.jpg'* -o -path '*/fanart/*.jpg' -o -path '*/extrafanart/*.jpg' \) -exec sh -c 'md5=$(md5sum < "$0") && md5=${md5%% *}.jpg && echo cp "$0" "/volume1/tv/_FANART/$md5"' {} \;
```

Every thing happens in the `sh` command (all commands are separated by `&&` but I omitted the `&&` for clarity):

```
md5=$(md5sum < "$0")
md5=${md5%% *}.jpg
cp "$0" "/volume1/tv/_FANART/$md5"'
```

the `$0` expands to the filename processed. We first compute the md5sum of the file, then only keep the md5sum (`md5sum` puts a hyphen next to the hash) and append `.jpg` to that, and finally we copy the file into the target folder, with the computed name.

**Notes.**

- I added

  ```
  -type d -path '/volume1/tv/_FANART` -prune -o
  ```

  to your command to omit this folder, since you very likely don't want to process it; it would actually be weird to process it, as its content is changed throughout `find`'s traversal.
- I left an `echo` in the command, so that absolutely nothing is copied (as is, it's 100% safe, you can just copy and paste it in your terminal): it only shows what commands are going to be performed (and you'll also see how fast/slow it is).
- The command is 100% safe regarding funny filenames with spaces, newlines, globs, etc.
- I used `md5sum < file`and not `md5sum file`, because if the filename `file` contains special characters (like backslashes, newlines, etc.), `md5sum` (at least my version) prepends the hash with a backslash. Weird. By not giving a filename, we're safe, this won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the files while giving them names according to their locations in the original directory tree.  For instance (":" is legal but
unusual in filenames), your "find" command could call a shell script (rather than "cp" directly), which might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "x$1" in
x/volume1/tv/_FANART/*)
    ;;
*)
    target=`echo "$1" | sed -e 's,^/volume1/tv/,,' -e s,/,:,g`
    cp "$1" "$2/$target"
    ;;
esac
```

and the corresponding "-exec" would be

```
-exec myscript "{}" /volume1/tv/_FANART \;
```

By the way, the source/destination on the original example are in the same directory tree "/volume1/tv", which is why the sample script uses a case statement - to exclude files already copied to the _FANART folder.

Comment: A colon is not the only useful punctuation character for this purpose, there are several "reasonable" choices including "@", "+" -- the tradeoff is whether the character exists in the filenames (making it a chance of collision), versus the ease of use within a shell script.

Comment: The reason why I suggested this mapping is that it seems more useful to keep some clue regarding the original locations of the files than to rename them randomly.